# SOAP call to function unable to enter 'for' loop (Python)

Tags: python, web-services, soap

My `SOAP` client calls a function where a list (`listOfObjects`) of objects is traversed in a `for` loop and it's attributes are appended to a new list, `listOfItems`. However when I run this SOAP call the `for` loop is never entered so the function just returns an empty list. If I give the `for` loop a normal list of strings to iterate over then it will do so perfectly fine. However it doesn't seem to want to iterate over a list of objects. Also, when I run the function without `SOAP` the `for` loop is entered with no problem. Does anyone know why this is happening when doing a `SOAP` call? Here is the code:

```
@srpc(String, _returns=Iterable(Unicode))
def displayItems(name):
    listOfItems = []
    global listOfObjects
    for i, o in enumerate(listOfObjects):
        listOfItems.append("%s %s %s %s" %(o.ID,o.townName,o.townLocation[0],o.townLocation[1]))                                
    return listOfItems
```

I realised that the problem is that my SOAP call is using a new 'fresh' object to access the function and subsuquently the list... now I need to know how to import the object used in a file to the SOAP client file where the SOAP call to the function is made.

Comment: Have you checked that the `listOfObjects` is not empty right before the for loop? ie.. can you print `listOfObjects` right before the for loop?

Comment: thanks @user3194712 but yes I've checked that and the for loop still isn't being run :/

Comment: actually no what am I talking about.. the list is empty before the for loop! :O so is the SOAP call taking the delcaration value of listOfObjects which is empty and not the listOfObjects which is being used in the program...?

Comment: the list is being populated without any SOAP call... so when a single SOAP call is made to that function the listOfObjects list is empty for some reason.. I don't understand why it hasn't got the stored objects in it which had been appended to the list using a normal function call (not a SOAP call)